# Check for new chat messages at background, Android

Tags: android, service, push-notification

I'm developing a application when which every 4,5 seconds the client checks whether the server responds "OK".

It's even working, But if I turn on/off the internet sometimes it stops working, it is inconsistent and I need to check the messages accurately.

And service stop like in example I gave and it re-operate outside the specified range of seconds (4.5)

I'm developing a chat, and I need to know this precisely, I need to be professional.

Start.java

```
public class Start extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackExec.class);
    getBaseContext().startService(serviceIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackExec.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
}}
```

BackExec.java

```
public class BackExec extends Service {

static Timer t;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    t =  new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String r = getData();
            if(r != null){
                if(r.equals("OK")){
                    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_ex);
                    b.setContentText("YOU HAVE NOTIFICATONS, CLICK.");
                    b.setContentTitle("TITLE APP:");
                    b.setOngoing(false);
                    b.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX); //TALVEZ FUNCIONE

                    NotificationManager m = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    m.notify(0, b.build());
                }

            }
        }
    }, 1, 4500);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    t =  new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String r = getData();
            if(r != null){
                if(r.equals("OK")){
                    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_ex);
                    b.setContentText("YOU HAVE NOTIFICATONS, CLICK.");
                    b.setContentTitle("TITLE APP:");
                    b.setOngoing(false);
                    b.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX); //TALVEZ FUNCIONE

                    NotificationManager m = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    m.notify(0, b.build());
                }

            }
        }
    }, 1, 4500);

    return START_STICKY;
}

public static String getData(){
    URL site = null;
    try {
        site = new URL("http://192.168.0.10:8080/example/server.php");
        URLConnection urlConn = site.openConnection();

        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("http://192.168.0.10:8080/example"));
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        PrintStream enviarInfos = new PrintStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());

        enviarInfos.print("pac=pac");
        urlConn.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String out = "";

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        out = out + inputLine;
        in.close();
        return out;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) { } // TO DO
public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
public void onStop() {}
public void onPause() {}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {} }
```

Comment: THat's a horrible design that will not scale as your users increase.  It also will kill their battery, and not work if the screen is off and Doze is entered. 
 Look into push messaging, where you push messages to the user rather than having them poll.

Comment: I can not understand, I transmit less than 1byte of information, I'm just using the internet, I want a simple solution equals "getData()" method.

And I do not want to use third-party server (Firebase, GCM) I want to use my.

Comment: Transmitting any information means the phone has to keep various radios on that it could otherwise turn off, and it needs to keep the processor on at full speed where it would otherwise reduce power.  Both of those kill the battery.  It won't scale because if you have a million users, that's a million users pinging your server 12 times a minute.  That's possible but will require far more hardware than a better solution.

Comment: Its also just wasteful as 99.9% of the time there will be no data for it to download.  The best solution is Firebase, GCM, etc because it multiplexes the same socket as other apps and will use the smallest amount of phone resources.  Second best would be a socket solution where you maintain a connection to an app on the server, and you can sleep waiting for that socket to wake up.  Which is more or less what Firebase, GCM, etc do.

Comment: the client would be waiting for information, like this code "while(socket.getInputStream ())" something like that, I do not remember.

Would it be this?

Comment: Thanks very much Gabe! I I implemented FCM and it worked well.You rock.